# Redirect nginx query string

Tags: redirect, nginx

We had a newsletter sent out with an incorrect query string, and we need to redirect to a valid query string in nginx

https://www.example.com/foo?categories=39%3Futm_source%3Dbar needs to be redirected to 
https://www.example.com/foo?categories=39&utm_source%3Dbar

Notice the extra `&` that we need to add after `39`

Answer (score 0):

For a single redirect of a URI with query string, you can use an `if` statement. The percent encoded characters should be used in their decoded form. For example:

```
if ($request_uri = '/foo?categories=39?utm_source=bar') { 
    return 301 /foo?categories=39&utm_source=bar;
}
```

See [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) for more.